# How to use RC4 securely

Tags: encryption, network

I want to encrypt my network communications with [RC4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4). The reason for choosing RC4 is the simple implementation and speed.

I need to have a pure Python implementation, because I cannot compile for my target system. My implementation is slightly modified from [TLS Lite](https://github.com/trevp/tlslite/blob/master/tlslite/utils/python_rc4.py).

If I understand [the security issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4#Security) correctly, the main problem is that the algorithm is not designed to be used with a [nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce). As proposed at Wikipedia, my approach is to generate an [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) hash of the key and a nonce and use this as encryption key.

Is this enough or do I have to implement the `dropN` variant, too? Any other weak spot I have to look at?

A fast and simple alternative to RC4 would be appreciated, too.

**Update** After reading *[Cryptology ePrint Archive: Report 2002/067](http://eprint.iacr.org/2002/067)*, I think I should definitely use the `dropN` approach (with at least 512 bytes).

**Update 2** Reviewing [my implementation](https://gist.github.com/2958701) would also be nice.

Comment: Doesn't python contain c implementations of crypto, say AES? Wouldn't that be just as portable, and faster?

Comment: @CodeInChaos read the question carefully: "because I cannot compile for my target system"

Comment: Somebody already compiled python for the target system. Doesn't the python standard library contain a pre-compiled crypto library? I'd expect that from most modern programming languages.

Comment: No, not on older Python versions. From Python 2.6 on there is SSL built-in, but I have to support Python 2.3.

Answer (score 3):

First: Do NOT use MD5. Ever. Never. Especially not in any form of security contexts. Use at least [SHA-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) or [SHA-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) (256 or 512/256 if speed is an issue on 64-bit machines). Apart from some legacy reasons, MD5 should be banned and the faster you stop using it the better you are off.

If you need a simple, pure Python RC4 implementation I have one at http://www.strombergson.com/files/rc4_gen.py.gz.

It is basically the same implementation we used as one of the sources for the test vectors in [RFC 6229](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6229).

Yes, you should use nBytes. Look at the arcfour128, arcfour256 defined in [RFC 4345](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4345) or some of the others we have calculated test vectors for.

I realise that I should move the RC4.py to [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub). And change the fingerprint to using something other than MD5. Facepalm. ;-)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the links. My implementation is pretty much the same but the test vectors are very useful and the advice to drop the first 1536 bytes is new, too.

Comment: If MD5 is not secure, you should tell Mozilla to turn off "security.ssl3.rsa_rc4_128_md5" by default.

Comment: Maybe you want to review my version (question updated).

Comment: I took a look at your implementation and it looks like a clean, simple implementation. I would suggesrt adding some KATS from RFC 6229 to show that it works. And some documentation.

Comment: Regarding md5 in SSLv3 you can disable these suites in your broswer. I would assume Mozilla knows about the status of md5, but includes it due to legacy support reasons.

Comment: For some good recommendations on crypto primitives to use, please see for example [recommendations by Cisco](http://www.cisco.com/web/about/security/intelligence/nextgen_crypto.html) or [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee321570.aspx)

Comment: Finally, [ECRYPT](http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/), the EU funded network of cryptographic experts provides [a yearly report on key lengths and primitives to use and not to use](http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/documents/D.SPA.17.pdf). A very good report.

Comment: The reason I so strongly suggesting not to use MD5 is that the more new designs use it, the longer it will take to phase out MD5. It is really bad work to specify MD5 into any new designs in 2012.

Comment: @JoachimStrömbergson Well, that was just an extract, so that's the reason for missing documentation and test. I added my test with vectors from RFC 6229 as further reference/help for other developers.

Comment: I included my key generation part using a hash. The nonce is a different, incremental value for each message. Is this fine?

Comment: The badness of MD5 is often exaggerated a bit, and SHA-1 isn't much better. It's vulnerable to collisions, but for example HMAC-MD5 with secret key is still secure. I don't see any attacks on the OP's use of MD5 to combine key and nonce. So while I'd avoid MD5 in a new system, it's not *that* bad. in fact the weaknesses of RC4 even with a good key affect the OP's system more than the weaknesses of MD5.

Answer (score 1):

[RC4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4) has a few shortcomings:

- It has no [Initialization Vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector) distinct from the key. If you use the same key twice, then you get twice the same sequence of pseudo-random bytes, and using that is a deadly sin. Thus, each key should be used only once (for a possibly long stream of bytes). Deriving the encryption key from a "master key" and a per-message random value, using a key derivation function (e.g. a hash function), can correct that *if done properly*.
- It has rather big biases in the first bytes. Dropping the first *N* bytes of output (for some value of *N* which should be a few hundreds) can fix that.
- It has small biases afterwards. These can be statistically exhibited over a few gigabytes of data. There is no known cure. These biases are rarely fatal.
- **RC4 is encryption only**. It does nothing for integrity. In any serious attack model, encryption *must* be coupled with a [MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code). Combining a symmetric cipher and a MAC securely [is not easy](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/202/should-we-mac-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-mac).

For all these reasons, the best way to use RC4 is often not to use it at all. Instead, use an [authenticated encryption mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) which does all the hard work; my favourite is [EAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAX_mode).

As for **performance**, consider that modern x86 CPU offer an [hardware implementation of AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set) against which RC4 will be an arthritic snail. If you nonetheless have an actual performance issue on an architecture which does not offer an hardware-optimized AES, then RC4 is not the best in class either; there are other [stream ciphers](http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/) which are both faster *and* more secure (all the stream ciphers from the current eSTREAM portfolio received a fair amount of scrutiny and went through unscathed).

Comment: It sounds like the OP is using something like MD5(key||nonce) as RC4 key, so the first point shouldn't affect him too much.

Comment: Well, ECRYPT itself doesn't recommend eSTREAM in its [annual report](http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/documents/D.SPA.20.pdf)

Comment: To be fair, ECRYPT says that it is just a bit too early to recommend the algorithms in the eSTREAM portfolio for general usage. They also say that the algorithms raise interest, have received and keep on receiving scrutiny, and that some have probably already been deployed in production by early adopters. My rule of thumb is to wait 5 years between publication and usage; the portfolio has been finalized in 2008 and we are now in 2013, so the algorithms are becoming "ripe" (at least in my own, necessarily subjective view).